# css html div moving to left not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my html code

```
    <body>
     <div id="head-title">
        <div id="box">
          <a href="#" id="divhide">
            <div>
                <div class="whiteline"></div>
                <div class="whiteline"></div>
                <div class="whiteline"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
        </div>
    </div>

      <div id="nav">    
        <?php echo $menu_item?>
      </div>

      <div id="main">

    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body
{
    margin:0px;
}

#head-title 
{
    height: 65px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #E67817;
}

#nav
{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    background: #1e293d;
    color: #465269;
}

#main
{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#box
{
    position:absolute;
    left:30px;
    top:14px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}

.whiteline
{
    margin-top:5px;
    border:2px solid white;
    width:25px;
}
```

i m moving div #nav to left using jquery

```
<script>
flag= true;
$('#divhide').click(function()
{
    if(flag)
    {
        $("#nav").css("marginLeft","0px").animate(
        {
            marginLeft: "-100"
        }, 1000);

        flag = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#nav").css("marginLeft","-100px").animate(
        {
            marginLeft: "=0"
        }, 1000);

        flag = true;
    }
});
</script>
```

but div on right hand side #main is not moving to left when div #nav move to left. and div #nav is not coming to original position correctly ie not in 1 sec it appears when i click on div so not getting moving like feel. any suggestions ?

Comment: can you post a working fiddle showing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. As per your css, you haven't set `height` for `<html> or <body>` , without height set for the parent elements, height specified in % won't work. so your `#nav` is not visible.
2. You haven't set any sort of `background` or `border` to #main and it does not have any content. Hence it's also not visible.

   check this working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/n5j9b/)
3. Since you have set `width:100px` for `#nav` and `width:100%` for `#main`, `#main` will breakdown to next line, if you want them to be in the same level change the width of `#main` to

`width:calc(100% - 100px)` (for advanced browsers with css3 support
    only)

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/n5j9b/2/)

Answer (score -1):

Your should update your javascript

`marginLeft: "-100"` as to be `marginLeft: "-100px"` and `marginLeft: "=0"` should be `marginLeft: "0"`

if this is still "not working" it means that the height of your nav is equals to 0... try update `height:100%` to `height:100px` for tests purpose.